# jQuery pulling value from input field

Tags: jquery, forms, variables, input

I am new to jQuery and right now I have a form that serves up a quote based on the number typed into an input field. Right now it's just pulling in and dividing by 2. I want to pull in another number from another field to change the number divisible in my equation. So let's say I have a field called multiplier and i want to pull that in to what i have how would I format this? The 0.50 is what I'd like to make a variable that pulls from the other input field.

```
$(function() {
// the minimum required value to be entered.
// in this case PayPal takes $0.35 from a $1
// donation, hence we ask for at least $1.35
var multiplier = $("#multiplier").val();
var minimum_value = 1.35;

// cache elements that are used at least twice
var $amount = $("#input_amount"),
$brandMatch = $("#autocomplete-ajax"),
    $msg = $("#msg"),
    $commission = $("#site_commission_box");

// attach handler to input keydown event

$amount.keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        return;
    }
    var amount = parseFloat($amount.val()),
    //brandMatch = 0.6;
        commission = amount * multiplier;

    if (isNaN(commission) || isNaN(amount)) {
        $msg.hide();
        $commission.hide();
        return;
    }

    if (amount <= minimum_value) {
        $commission.hide();
        $msg
            .text("Please fill in a higher amount")
            .fadeIn();
    } else {
        $msg.hide();
        $commission
            .fadeIn()
            .find("span")
            //.text((amount - commission).toFixed(2));
            .text((amount - commission).toFixed(2));
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get a value from a form anywhere using jQuery, use the `$("someElementHere").val();` syntax. Essentially where you are calling the element you are denoting that you'd like to grab the value, though if you use `val("Some text here");` you can then set the element's new value.
Hope this helps!

Example:
`<input id="multiplier" value="2">`
Then in JS
`var multiplier = $("#multiplier").val();`
then just use the `multiplier` var anywhere!

Also as a note, I use `value="2"` because it will allow you to see a default value of /2, but you could use any default value!

Comment: So I just tried to implement your suggestion and want to make sure I added it in the right spots since it's not working for me. In my input field I added the id "multiplier" up top I added `  var multiplier = $("#multiplier").val(); ` and in the equation I added `commission = amount * multiplier;`

Comment: Did you add that new ID in a NEW input element and keep the old input field "amount" the same?

Comment: Actually it is working when I hardcode value="2" but I want it to read the value as it's typed in so i can change what's in the field to see the quote

Comment: would I use the onkeyup for this?

Comment: I would use onkeyup and make it run the function of the whole script so that you can live update results.

Comment: Can you show me what this would need to be formatted like?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: `function doSomething() {
    var amount = $("#amount").val();
    var multiplier = $("#multiplier").val();
    var result = amount * multiplier;
    $("#result").html(result);
}` and html: `Amount: <input id="amount" value="6" onkeyup="doSomthing()">
<br>
Multiplier: <input id="multiplier" value="2" onkeyup="doSomthing()">
<br>
<span id="result"></span>`

Comment: I'm sure where in the script I need to add in the listener for the keyup multiplier, I updated my code above so you can see what I have right now.

Comment: Where you have $amount.keyup, I suggest naming that: update() or the likes of it, then make two anon functions for keyup on $amount and $multiplier and simply call update() from those functions. However to do this you will also need to ensure you are setting all changeable values within the update function as to ensure you have the latest versions of them.

Comment: can you show me what the update portion might look like, I've tried this a few different ways but am having trouble connecting together

Comment: I think i understand how to do that, but what I am asking is how would I format the part in the update function that marries together the 2 fields.

Comment: This is my function code, can you show me how I should stack in the keyup updates as you suggested? `function doSomething() {
    var multiplier = $("#autocomplete-ajax").val();
    var amount = $("#amount").val();
    var result = amount * multiplier;

    $("#result").html(result); }`

Comment: Update to the code after adding in update `function update() {
    var multiplier = $("#autocomplete-ajax").val();
    var amount = $("#amount").val();
    var result = amount * multiplier;

    $multiplier.keyup(function(e) {
    var multiplier = parseFloat($multiplier.val()),
    }

    $amount.keyup(function(e) {
        var amount = parseFloat($amount.val()),
    }



    $("#result").html(result); }
`

Comment: I will put something together shortly, I had a burst of creativity for some stuff at work. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks Aaron! This was exactly what I needed! Worked beautifully and is easy to understand!